# How to Map a MS SQL table to an offset in the the MDF file?

Tags: sql-server

I have reasonably unusual requirement related to the development of a storage product in which I am looking for ways to map a table(s) inside the MS SQL db to  its corresponding storage sectors on disk. For that what I am trying to get is the file offset ( or offsets ) in side the mdf file for a particular table along with the data in the table. Does MS SQL provide such kinda ( table data to db file offset ) information in a documented way like a SQL proc or query to get this information? If so how to get it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's very likely there's a more reasonable way to do it than dealing with the raw `mdf`. Not to mention that the data might be written to the MDF at any point - it's only the *combination* of MDF and LDF that gives you a consistent database state.

Answer (score 1):

The information is available, yes. Read the following articles:

- [Understanding Pages and Extents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Managing Space Used by Objects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187501(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Table and Index Organization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

**Everything** you need in there. Please read them thoroughly, if you have follow up question then go back and read again because the answer **is** in there.

That being said, you are doing a [fools errand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe_hunt).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support guys, Yes I do agree that it is fairly insane stuff I am trying to achieve.

But I figured out the solution and it working perfect.

Undocumented "DBCC IND" did most of the work.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/12/13/more-undocumented-fun_3a00_-dbcc-ind_2c00_-dbcc-page_2c00_-and-off_2d00_row-columns.aspx

FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS should do the mdf to disk sector mapping.

http://www.wd-3.com/archive/luserland.htm

Apologies that I not able to explain what exactly what doing due to IP reasons.